# Как выложить html файл?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Создаю новое spring-boot приложение, хочу чтобы дефолтный контроллер возвращал html, подскажите как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html** - это строка !!

Можно, например, вывести просто строку:

```
@GetMapping({"/", "/index.html"})
public String index() {
    return "Hello world";
}
```

а можно воспользоваться разметкой. Например как-то так:

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
    private String page;

    @GetMapping({"/", "/index.html"})
    public String index() {
        if (this.page == null) {
            constructPage();
        }
        return this.page;
    }

    private void constructPage() {
        StringBuilder page = new StringBuilder();
        page.append("<html>");
        page.append("<head>");
        page.append("<title>Hello world</title>");
        page.append("</head>");
        page.append("<body>");
        page.append("<h1>Hello world</h1>");
        page.append("</body>");
        page.append("</html>");

        this.page = page.toString();
    }
}
```